# Image behind navigation bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

to make a landing page for my project  like [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/)    using bootstrap 4 and        html not able to hide background-image behind navigation bar

Comment: You forgot to add a question. And eventually what you have tried, etc...

Comment: What have you tried to far?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this on my **Codepen** account, the only difference is you'll have to change where I've put the logo to a navigation bar and don't make it center of the img div, make it push to the top like the example you provided.

See below:

```
<div class="header_img">

    <div class="row logo-container-div align-items-center justify-content-center">
     <div class="logo-wrapper col-auto" >
       <h1>LOGO HERE</h1>
       <p>Some additional text</p>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.header_img {
    height: 800px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(150deg, rgba(68, 0, 139, 0.7), rgba(47, 0, 120, 0.6) 10%, rgba(27, 57, 129, 0.5) 30%, rgba(41, 123, 192, 0.5) 50%, rgba(114, 240, 255, 0.6) 86%, rgba(84, 183, 249, 0.7)), url("http://www.strawberryproofing.co.uk/images/nature_large1.png");
    background-position: 0%, 0%, 50%, 50%;
    background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
    background-size: auto, cover;
}


.logo-container-div {
  min-height: 70vh;

}

.logo-wrapper {

    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    padding: 25px 30px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    position: fixed;

  }

.logo-wrapper h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.logo-wrapper p {
 font-size: 18px; 
}
```

See it here: https://codepen.io/billyfarroll/pen/qYWYYV

You'll want the `flex` : `justify` and `align` elements and the `background-position` & `background-size`

Answer (score 0):

What I understand by your question is that you what to hide your image behind the nav bar after scrolling the page, for this you have to fix the nav bar. You just use "position : fixed" to your nav bar class.